# How to convert RGB to CMYK color code?

Tags: cmyk, rgb, color-conversion, color-spaces, color-reproduction

I want to convert RGB to CMYK color code, but unfortunately, I have some problem with colors.
I want to use this color #31C68B in Photoshop, and after that I want to print that for Visit Card and the other printing product.
But when I see the color on my monitor, the color is not good.
I think the main problem in source file based on RGB color. If you have any experience for this issue, or any other idea for solving this problem, please let me know.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Related, useful and possible duplicate: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/problem-converting-color-from-rgb-to-cmyk-for-print

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't mean to sound pedantic, but you might want to read into the very basics of `RGB`  vs. `CMYK`, mainly the difference in *gamut*. `#31C68B` is an `RGB` colour that is outside of `CMYK`'s gamut, which means that it *cannot* be reproduced in that colour space.

This is actually indicated in Photoshop's colour picker when you select the colour:

[image: out of gamut warning in photoshop's colour picker]

What you'll want to do is to try and *approximate* the `RGB` colour as good as possible with a `CMYK` colour of your choosing. Photoshop does this automatically for you, but sometimes its processes aren't always optimal.

That said, unless you extensively colour-calibrated your system, matching on-screen colours with printed ones is quite the crapshoot, with lots of experience being the main tool.

An (expensive) alternative is to choose a `PMS` (Pantone) colour that matches your `RGB` colour and have your work printed in that.