# Non CMYK color in branding?

Tags: branding, identity

[image]

This is an identity designed by Pentagram. The blue used here is not a CMYK color. How do use such colors in your branding when there is print involved ?

Comment: Not CMYK can mean 2 things: That it is a spot color (panatone color or other such thing like say RAL) or that its RGB. But basically you need to specify 3 colors, one for spot colors, one for RGB and one for CMYK. Remember choosing a CMYK color is a cost saving measure, if your client can not afford to print in your color they will just ignore your guide.

Comment: Related: [Problem converting color from RGB to CMYK for print](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/6107/23061)

Answer (score 8):

Most branding use Pantone colors along CMYK and RGB colors. PMS (Pantone Matching System) allows for more precision in the reproduction of colors by using 10 different inks (as opposed to 4 for CMYK).

These colors are usually documented in a [branding style guide](https://www.expediagroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Expedia-Group-Brand-Guidelines_Compact_Final.pdf). In the case of Expedia, you can find the blue on page 20 and its recommended values in various systems:

[image]

Sometimes numbers for PMS C (Coated) and PMS U (Uncoated) may vary and you will need to pick the ink with regards to the type of paper that will be used.

Pantone colors are available in design software (though sometimes a bit buried), so that you can fetch the exact color you need to use if creating a piece for this brand.

Some brands even use trademarked Pantone colors. For example [Tiffany worked with Pantone to design their very own Tiffany Blue](https://www.pantone.com/crazy-about-tiffanys-the-story-behind-an-iconic-brand-color).

Comment: What standard does the RGB and CMYK adhere to?

Comment: @joojaa I'm not sure what you are asking specifically?

Comment: It’s worth adding that major, global brands would never use Pantone references if they know what they are doing. Even Pantone advise against it now. Professional brand managers use custom colour specifications based on Lab or spectral data  to control the colour of their products, marketing materials and packaging.

Comment: @Emilie RGB numbers, hex numbers and cmyk percentages dont mean anything if you do not include what color profile they adhere to. Its a common mistake, and often omitted but its still wrong. So is the  RGB: sRGB, ProPhoto, Adobe RGB ditto for CMYK is it SWOP, GraCol, FOGRA...

Comment: @Westside yes because Lab is actually same no matter what. As for spectral colors that is a bit of overkill though having some very weird metamer in spectral could be nice.

Comment: @joojaa I get what you're saying now. Can't recall ever seeing a brand guide that went so far as specifying the profile too. Would love to see one if someone has a sample!

Comment: @Westside Do you have a source for this? (i.e. "Even Pantone advise against it now.") Not being annoying, genuine interest :)

Comment: @joojaa FYI Spectral data is definitely not overkill if you are serious about colour control. It allows you to separate substrate from ink and varnish and is the only (good) way to produce fully accurate digital proofs, given the right hardware and software. Companies like Pantone, XRite and GMG all agree that it is the future.

Comment: @Emilie my only source would be meetings that I’ve had with Pantone. They are moving away from Pantone swatches and books, via Pantone Live to more accurate systems such as ColorCert. Only relevant for serious brand colour control right now, but that’s the direction that the industry is headed.

Comment: @Westside As mentioned to joojaa above, also interested in a style guide implementing this or even recommendations about how it should be implemented in a style guide, if you ever run into one. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @Emilie that kind of colour management is way beyond style guides and way beyond the scope of a comment on this site. Basically, you start from a Pantone colour (or whatever) and then establish a brand colour based on iterations of print trials on various substrates and using various print methods (as relevant). It’s a whole job (and a very expensive process) in itself.

Comment: @Westside I will turn my comment into a question since I think that's valuable info to elaborate... if you don't mind staying in tune to provide an answer :)

Comment: @Westside maybe but not many people can test spectral data. I eman i have a spectrometer and i can simulate it somehow but i cant test a spectral swatch even if i wanted to. Yeah i even have a not so fancy spectral camera available for me.

Comment: @Emilie defining the profile should be easy, your test prints were done with something and your color guide used something as reference just state that in your guide.

Comment: Please have a go at [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/110416/which-systems-are-replacing-the-use-of-pms-for-color-control-and-how-does-one-go) if you have time!

Comment: @joojaa: Hex numbers without a specified color profile might yield slightly different colors in different contexts, but sometimes it's necessary to rdner logos into formats like GIF or JPG that generally use "hope for the best" semantics.

Comment: @supercat sure but it does not hurt to tell that you probably mean sRGB to stop any confusion about it.

Comment: @joojaa: Does GIF support annotations to indicate color space?  I guess JPG should, given its use in photography, so that may have been a poor example, but does GIF?

Comment: @supercat no but then the browser just assumes sRGB. The reason you state it is sRGB is so that people dont get confused down the line and start talking of stupid things like disabling color management. Anyway times will change and one day that reasoning might not be so evident. Designs guides are supposed to think these kinds of things for the user after all.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78904/discussion-on-answer-by-emilie-non-cmyk-color-in-branding).