# Color shift when image is converted to CMYK

Tags: color, cmyk, print-production, color-conversion, rgb

I'm working with a graphic designer to design a book cover for a self-published title of mine on Amazon. The purple in the cover image becomes dull when converted to the required CMYK.

Original Image
[image]

This is what it looks like after being converted.

[image]

The designer has adjusted the hue and saturation levels before the conversion to try to compensate but it's not working. Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: There is no solution for this question. Simply the cmyk pront can not be that saturated. Period. But also the image isnt actually that dull either as the  images surrounding is not as saturated either so your eye will compensate. You should probably lighten the image a bit.

Comment: It becomes dull when it's (simulated) ink and not light. This should not be a surprise. Books are not LCDs. CMYK is not RGB. Ink is not as bright as light coming from a monitor. Your designer must learn how color reproduction actually works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem converting color from RGB to CMYK for print](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/problem-converting-color-from-rgb-to-cmyk-for-print)

Comment: Best practice for me is to **never** show any client an RGB image if a piece is destined to be printed. It's *always* haphazard to show a client an RGB image and get approval *knowing* color shifts **will** happen when converting things to CMYk for print. Truth is.. as a client, you should have never seen the oversaturated and vibrant RGB image. That way, you don't expect something that is simply not possible from a press.

Comment: Not related to the image colours, but your back cover needs work. The front and spine both look great; the back, not so much. The huge initial P isn’t working, the margins are too narrow, the font is uninspired (why aren’t you using the same font as on the front and spine?), the tracking is too large (or point size too small), the purple colour is too bright and light for text, the website link is too bulky, and using Myriad for the author blurb and website link just has the effect of making it look cheap (to my eye, at least). Looks like it was knocked up in Word by a non-designer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is always a significant difference between RGB and CMYK whatever conversion you're doing.

Yes, RGB tends to be significantly brighter and/or more saturated, than the converted CMYK equivalent.

No, the final print on paper **will not** look like any of the RGB and CMYK variations on-screen. The end product will also look slightly off.

No, the designer has nothing to do with this. It is the way it works.

That's a good design. Once you get to your next books, you won't even be thinking about this anymore :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment! I'm going to wait to see the physical copy. I'm sure it'll be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the book cover file in RGB mode and try to find a place that does giclée print. This will give wider color gamut than other printers. The cost will be much higher. Seems like the only way to solve the color "problem".

Comment: There are different digital print methods which will give wider gamut than standard digital print and offset print, but it doesn't *remove* the issue, it just *minimizes* it. Be aware that the paper used might not be suitable for a book cover. This must be cleared with the print house/bookbinder.