# Exporting InDesign PDF with RGB converted to CMYK, colours look dark and muted?

Tags: adobe-indesign, cmyk, print-production, color-conversion, color-profile

I am working on a publication in InDesign, working on a 2019 Macbook Pro display, in which there are around 300 links to images. Some images are in RGB, and some in CMYK. Here is an example of an image on-screen:

[image]

I would like to prepare the file for printing, by making sure all images are converted to CMYK. I have tried all the different options in the `output` section of the Export PDF dialogue...

I notice that when `Profile Inclusion Policy` is set to `Don't Include Profile` (as requested by the printer) – the exported PDF looks very darkened and dull in the System Viewer (Preview), going into greenish-yellow:

[image]

However, when I open it in Adobe Acrobat Pro, the colours looks much more true to the original:

[image]

I would like to know how to convert my whole PDF to CMYK, and preserve the nice colours, while not including the profile in the PDF (as the printer requested)...

I would be very thankful for the correct course of action, to deliver to the printer a CMYK-only PDF, with colours as faithful to the original as possible.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to use the correct CMYK profile recommended by the printer, and it's quite a big subject really. But one thing I can quickly tell you is that Mac's Preview is **not** to be trusted when it comes to print PDFs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The thing is that the printer recommended not including any profile, but just sending a CMYK-only PDF... However, when I do that, the colours on Preview look so muddy... Which makes me scared that the prints might come out wrong...

Comment: *"preview is not to be trusted"* truer words have never been spoken. Acrobat is much more trustworthy for preview, especially if one calibrates the monitor

Comment: See this related question, if not quite a duplicate: [Problem converting from RGB to CMYK for print](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/problem-converting-color-from-rgb-to-cmyk-for-print).

Comment: To not *include* a profile is not the same as to not use a profile for *conversion*. Actually there is no way you can convert from RGB to CMYK without using a profile. It's set in *Export Adobe PDF > Output > Color > Destination*. For your colors to look on print as they look on screen, you have to use the color profile recommended by the printer. And to get proper preview in Acrobat you have to make sure to set *Output Preview > Simulate > Simulation Profile* to the same profile. If they don't recommend one? Uhm, that's a bad sign. That probably means you can never expect color likeness.

Comment: Actually some of your images already being CMYK might be a problem if they have been converted to another profile than recommended. Sorry, it's just a bit of a complicated subject. I might make an answer later or perhaps post some links to similar questions.

Comment: I rarely understand why people use RGB images in InDesign if a project is destined for CMYK printing. Use CMYK images. Don't trust software to auto-convert between color modes for you. And yeah.. FORGET you have "Preview" installed on your Mac - use Acrobat.

Comment: Thank you for all the useful advice – I have converted all the images I could from RGB to CMYK in Photoshop. However, there are about 50 vector drawing + custom font PDFs that are in RGB color space, that I could not convert into CMYK without rasterizing... hence my dilemma.

Comment: What's a "custom font PDF"? Vector drawings can be converted *without* rasterizing. I don't mean to imply it's always a one-click, easy, task, but it can be done.

Comment: My go-to way of converting vector drawings from RGB to CMYK would be to open them up in Illustrator, and convert them there; with custom PDF fonts (that are sadly not embedded), the PDF breaks when opening it there... So, my question would be: how to convert such a PDF vector drawing without rasterising?

Comment: This may be getting a bit too file specific. If the drawings are PDFs and contain type, and maintaining the font is imperative, you may need to purchase the font. Or replace the type with a font you do have. The amount of effort all depends on the amount of craftsmanship you want to exert. If the colors in the auto-converted RGB>CMYK images are not acceptable, I assumed you want a high level of craftsmanship.. which often means more effort. If the images in the question are acceptable after manually converting them to CMYK, then you may be okay with the placed RGB PDFs being auto-converted.

Comment: @Scott I **never** convert RGB images to CMYK for print jobs – ever. In my experience, it leads to nothing but trouble and lower-quality output. I leave the images as RGB and send them off so the printer can colour correct them according to _their_ equipment and calibrations. I then export the PDF as CMYK (preserve numbers), using the printer’s profile. That is how every printer we work with recommends doing it. I cannot possibly hope to colour-correct for a specific colour profile, paper type and machine on my own machine.

Comment: Welp `:)` I'm the opposite @JanusBahsJacquet I **never** use RGB images... because I want to control how the images appear. With proper profiles, what I send in CMYK is what I get back on stock.

Comment: @Scott That’s just it – I _cannot_ control how it ends up looking on stock from my end, because regardless of profiles, my monitor is not calibrated to the printers’ equipment. Theirs is. When I get the files back from them, they always look different to how I want them to end up looking, but once printed, they match exactly. In some cases, they’ve CMYK’ed the images when colour-correcting, but if I CMYK before sending to them, I’m removing colour information and reducing the chances of the final conversion being accurate.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet just different worlds. My print providers would kick back a PDFx file (which is mostly what I send) containing RGB images.

Comment: @Scott Oh the PDF for print is all CMYK – no RGB there. They’d throw that back in an instant. I do the layout in InDesign, then send (or upload or share) all the actual image files to them, their graphic designer goes through and adjusts each image so the colours look just right for the stock in question on their press, then they send them back, I update the links in InDesign, export as PDF with “Convert to profile (preserve numbers)” and send them the CMYK PDF. Then they send hard proofs of a selection of the images so I can check before printing the final book.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yup, just different worlds. I send PDFx files almost exclusively and always set to "convert preserve numbers". No one else color corrects images for me. That's my job `:)` I deal with myriad print providers and often don't know which of them will actually be doing the printing until PDFx files are ready for delivery.

Comment: @Scott Most of mine are PDFx as well (unless the printer requests a different format). And I do do the colour-correction, of course – but I can’t trust that the colour-correction that looks right on my screen and printer will also look right on their equipment. Every combination of printing press and stock produces a unique colour result, and there’s no way for anyone to consistently predict that except on their calibrated machines with their experience of the press, so they go through it on their end _after_ my editing, to make sure the end result on _their_ press matches what I want.

Comment: (I only deal with two or three printers, because anything more would be too much of a quality risk for me. I cannot trust a workflow where I don’t have direct, personal contact and experience with the printer; the ones I do deal with are people I’ve known and worked with for over a decade.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I've been lucky. My calibration here has been dead on for years. (which is why I hate system upgrades and hardware changes) I deal with about 5 printers... but I never know which one will ultimately get the job. There's a "middle man" which sends me the design work, then is responsible for hiring printing. Things typically run very smooth and I've dealt with all of the printers long enough that they don't hesitate to skip the middleman and contact ME directly if they know it's my file and something arises (which is invaluable).

Comment: Sound's like our relationships with print providers is very similar `:)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134255/discussion-between-scott-and-janus-bahs-jacquet).

Answer (score -1):

In fact, when you convert RGB to CMYK, the color is impossible to be consistent.
*([See why](https://www.qinprinting.com/cmyk-and-rgb/))*

We suggest that you'd better convert the RGB image into CMYK in Adobe Photoshop. when you finish the conversion, you can see that the image is darker than before. Then you can use PS to adjust the color to make it achieve the effect you want as much as possible. Save the picture as CMYK and then use it in InDesign.
When exporting PDF using InDesign, select no color conversion and do not include the profile.