# How do I make this vectors on Adobe Ilustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, logo, svg, images

This is my first posting a question on Graphic Design Stack Exchange. I have the following needs:

I need to revectorize this logo

[image]

But I'm trying to, and my result looks something like this:

[image]

The cupcakes, cap and gift from the second image are almost vanished because I used quick tracing. I also need to restore those things and to export the new vectorize logo in a way that it doesn't look bad when you zoom it. But I don't have much knowledge of the tools from the software to do those things and the image that I exported is very poor compared to the original.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: People, I'm trying to do the gradient, like you explained on your comments, and I cannot achieve it. My gradient looks like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UM-mFu5JNcLSBNnU3HNxvwqGfCHr5z-0/view?usp=sharing), and I need to put it like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DpJXur0TeGF1569WaK2_f7VKFc7pbpNJ/view?usp=sharing), because my customer doesn't want the logo be very dark, but bright, and I don't how to achieve this gradient.

Comment: @Scott Help! Please...

Comment: It appears to me like you are trying to achieve the vibrance of the RGB gradient with CMYK colors. That's not going to happen. CMYK colors *are* going to be less vibrant. It's the nature of CMYK.  Some RGB colors are *not* possible in CMYK. All you can do is try to get as close as you can. [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84tEA.png)

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/problem-converting-color-from-rgb-to-cmyk-for-print

Comment: I think the problem lies in my little knowledge about putting a gradient using adobe illustrator. When I try to replicate the bright logo, I get something like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OJZereE70-J8pyy3JRViM3zrPe8qUM_9/view?usp=sharing). When I try to do the gradient, I scan the bright logo and I get the Hexcode from the colors of it, and then I put these codes on the new logo that I'm trying to create. However, I don't know how to proceed to emulate the gradient.

Comment: ermm... https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/gradients.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Open original in **Photoshop**
- Enlarge 200%
- change mode to Greyscale
- `Levels`, `Curves`, or `Threshold` to get a solid black and white image
- Save

[image]

- Open saved image in Illustrator
- Run Image trace
- Tweak `Threshold` there as needed
  [image]
- Expand trace

  - **Extra:** I like to try and avoid [conflation artifacts](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/65060/3270) where possible. While they aren't *really* an issue with *white* on a color, these are standard extra steps I take...
  - Select white objects `Edit > Cut`
  - You should see merely the outer shape. If it's a *compound shape* with holes in it where white objects were, select the inner "hole" shapes and delete them. The goal is a simple, single shape for that outer outline.
  - Apply gradient to (remaining) background shape.
  - `Edit > Paste in Front` to get the white objects back (Paste in Front ensures they are in the same, original, position)
- Select All
- `Object > Group` (of note, I would *not* create a compound shape here so that the white objects remain white. If you wanted white to be transparent, then `Object > Compound Path > Make` would work)

[image]

---

By enlarging the image in Photoshop, you get better results for minute details such as the star on the hat, the circles are traced more as circles and there's less detail lost overall. Really though, that particular logo is *not* designed to be reduced too much. The details are very thin and will plug up (like the line between the balloons) once you pass a certain reduction size.

**Ideally though**... I would personally just redraw it *manually* tracing the original image - paths are always constructed better that way. Tracing is just a "good enough" venture most of the time. *Minimally*, I'd redraw the outer shape so it's smooth because it's a little ragged when traced due to the shadow the original has.

Comment: You can remove the shadow completely with a *Black & White* adjustment layer. Choose the *Maximum White* preset and set the blend mode to *Divide*. Like [this](https://i.imgur.com/mN3GdQu.gif).

Comment: @Wolff More work than I'd do `:)`.. I'd honestly just redraw at least the outer shape (If not the entire thing). I generally don't like auto-tracing anything It's a 20-30 minute thing to redraw it entirely.

Comment: I agree. I end up spending so much time tweaking the image and the auto-tracing that I regret I didn't just start drawing right away. I do however in some cases just make a 1200/2400 PPI 1-bit image in the wanted size though.

Comment: Thanks so much for your responses. It truly help to the job. I know that it's better to vectorize manually than using quick tracing, but nevertheless, the new result looks better than the second image that I posted.

Comment: I'm having a problem regarding the gradient. I put an explanation on the section comment of my post. Please, I need some help.

Answer (score 4):

1. In Photoshop use threshold to turn the image black and white:
   [image]

2.Back in illustrator run tracing, the effect should be more accurate. Add the gradient/shadow to the expanded tracing result.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response!!! I did the steps that you and Scott listed and I worked!!! The only thing is that I need to fix the gradient to be as close as the original image, but it looks good!

Comment: @rippleytrigger if you run curves on the original image in ps then you can force the gradient closer to a line. Then its easier to estimate the direction and origin of the gradient. (Pro tip)

Comment: Hi. I'm having a problem regarding the gradient. I put an explanation on the section comment of my post. Please, I need some help.