# PSD image in Indesign colours corrupted when PDF, but JPEG ok - why?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I've noticed that if I place a photoshop PSD image into an InDesign file and then export that InDesign file as a PDF the resulting image in the PDF has its colours washed out or its contrast looks off.

If I export the image from a PSD to a JPEG first, then place the JPEG into the InDesign file and export the InDesign file as PDF the resulting image in the PDF is much truer to the image when viewed in photoshop.

Both the JPEG and PSD are saved as RGB, and the PDF is CMYK, but i wouldnt have thought this would have mattered as the PDF export settings in InDesign ive set "convert to destination (preserve numbers)" in the colour output tab.

Why is this and is there anything i can do to use the photoshop files in indesign instead of having to export them as JPEGs first ?

Comment: What are youd color management settings for the files

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Did you save the PDF as a CMYK document for printing?  If so, that could be the problem.  If the Photoshop document is in RGB, then conversion to CMYK can often lead to washed out colours, because some of the colours in RGB are not possible to be printed properly in CMYK.  This is only a guess though. You should check what colour format the image is in.

Comment: @BillyKerr ive updated the question to add that info

Comment: @sam preserve numbers does not do what you think it does but especially from rgb to cmyk what exactly is it supposed to preserve?

Comment: @joojaa im not sure.. never really considered it. Whats the best workflow for me to acehive a print ready CMYK PDF given that most of my image assets are PSD and JPEGs currently saved as RGB. Note i also use the same image assets for digital so ideally dont want to have to keep separate CMYK and RGB copies, was hoping inDesign would sort this for me at export.

Comment: color conversion isnt about taking color A and keeping color A in all conditions. it also deals with what to do if you cant get color A. In this case you probably cannot.

Comment: Yes the colour conversion from RGB to CMYK is likely what is causing the problem.  Next you would really have to look at which colours in your PSD are out of gamut for CMYK printing, or you could convert to CMYK in Photoshop and make colour corrections so it doesn't look so bad.  Converting RGB to CMYK is often a problem that causes washed out/desaturated colours, because some very bright saturated colours such as vivid blues/greens can't be printed in CMYK.  [see this related question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/problem-converting-color-from-rgb-to-cmyk-for-print)

Comment: Thanks @BillyKerr any idea why if i export the PSD to JPEG and then update the link in inDesign to point at the JPEG the resulting image in the PDF is better (although its still slightly converted in the PDF, its 90% ok, were as the PSD was not workable at all in terms of colour) ? Even though both the PSD and JPEG are RGB

Comment: Just to add, the only option i have set to enabled when exporting the JPEG from PSD is "Embed Colour Profile : Adobe RGB 1998"

Comment: @sam - There's a possibility that the image is not being converted, or the conversion is just being bypassed, because it's a linked image.  I am not massively experienced with InDesign, but in Illustrator it is possible to do this and end up with an RGB image in a CMYK PDF.  This could cause problems when printing.  It might look OK on screen, but the RGB colours that are out of gamut might still not print well. It could also cause your print job to be rejected, for example if you are going to have a job printed using lithography or screen printing, where separations are required.